# Is it possible to capture specific parts of a PDF text with AWS Textract?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip

I need to extract the text from the PDF, but I don't want the entire PDF to be parsed. I wonder if it's possible to get specific parts of the parsed PDF. For example, I have a PDF with information about: Address, city and country. I don't want everything returned, just the Address field, not the other information.

Code that returns the text to me:

```
from textractcaller.t_call import call_textract
from textractprettyprinter.t_pretty_print import get_lines_string

response = call_textract(input_document="s3://my-bucket/myfile.pdf") 
print(get_lines_string(response))
```

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: I edited the question, tried to be more specific. @Hcaertnit

Comment: Thanks! That'll make it easier for others who are more skilled than I to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method (it doesn't use AWS Textract, but works as well):

```
import PyPDF2

def extract_text(filename, page_number):
    # Returns the content of a given page
    pdf_file_object = open(filename, 'rb')
    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file_object)
    # page_number - 1 below because in python, page 1 is considered as page 0
    page_object = pdf_reader.getPage(page_number - 1)
    text = page_object.extractText()
    pdf_file_object.close()
    return text
```

This function extracts the text from one single PDF page.
If you haven't got PyPDF2 yet, install it through the command line with 'pip install PyPDF2'.

Comment: OK! It's not quite what I need, but being able to select the text extraction page is already great. Thanks!